# Fluid table cells on small screens: Packing cells into multiple rows

Tags: html, css

I got some table data to display, using a standard HTML table. I can predict a bit about the cell width based on the data type, but not much (names may be loong, the description may only be one word):

```
+--------------+--------------+-----+------+----------------------------------------------+
| name surname | name surname | num | date | one or two sentences making up a description |
+--------------+--------------+-----+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Now this data should also be readable on an android smartphone and other small devices. The problem is that even with a very small font size, the resulting table is wider than the screen. You can see the problem here in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/orithena/nbbaU/4/ (resize the result window, if necessary on your wide screen).

If the table overflows to the right, I want the row to split up into two rows while one cell spans both rows -- and if one row flows together, every row should do it (even the table header row). And I'd like to have a wider border-spacing between these "double-rows" so that the user has a visual cue to interpret them as "one row":

```
+==============+======+======================+
| name surname | num  | one or two sentences |
+--------------+------+ making up a          |
| name surname | date | description          |
+==============+======+======================+
```

Here's a mockup of the desired result, but it's ugly markup (helper cells, semantic cell order is jumbled up for screen readers) -- and it's static, i.e. must be done server-side: http://jsfiddle.net/orithena/wwCYU/4/

Is there any way to achieve flowing table cells without reordering the cells nor using helper cells? Preferably without using divs in each table cell nor Javascript/jQuery? Media queries would be okay, I think, although they don't fully solve the problem.

I did not even find the problem on the web, but maybe I'm just using the wrong keywords... (Oh, and it does not have to be IE-compatible).

Comment: Uhm, just setting a max-width (say, `max-width: 100%;`, as in, don't get bigger than the whole page) to your table and adjusting your columns... Wouldn't that do? If not, use the `rowspan` attribute to set a cell to covering two rows. `<td rowspan="2">Content</td>` Can also be done horizontally using `colspan`.

Comment: Perhaps it wouldn't work unless using Javascript.

Comment: @Ariane nope, max-width wouldn't work. Try it out in the first fiddle link. And using rowspan would require to break up the semantic order of the cells on server-side -- and wide screens would also receive the collapsed version (I implemented it that way, see second fiddle).

Comment: @mayaa I fear so, too.

Comment: @maligree I'm going to have to agree that this will require either a dirty solution like allowing words to break anywhere, either JS. For example you could make some columns' text vertical (possible with CSS3, right?) if screen width < X. Or add a `rowspan` using JS if the screen's width is insufficient.